# How can I increase the number of results returned?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, collegescorecard

The following request:

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?fields=school.name,school.city,school.state,school.zip,school.carnegie_size_setting
```

Returns just 20, how can I get all 7175?

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "total": 7175,
    "page": 0,
    "per_page": 100
  },
  "results": [
   ....
```

Comment: Something is missing in your request: a question mark, ampersand? Please [edit]

Answer (score 1):

From [Open Data Maker HTTP API](https://github.com/RTICWDT/open-data-maker/blob/master/API.md#pagination-with-_page-and-_per_page):

> By default, results are returned in pages of 20 records at a time. To retrieve pages after the first, set the `_page` option parameter to the number of the page you wish to retrieve. Page numbers start at zero; so, to return records 21 through 40, use `_page=1`. Remember that the `total` number of records available for a given query is given in the total field of the top-level `metadata` object.
>
> You can also change the number of records returned per page using the `_per_page` option parameter, up to a maximum of 100 records. Bear in mind, however, that large result pages will increase the amount of JSON returned and reduce the performance of the API.

Thus, your request should be:

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?_per_page=100&_page=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY&fields=school.name,school.city,school.state,school.zip,school.carnegie_size_setting
```

Then change `_page` to `1` etc.

You could use e.g. [cURL globbing](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-globbing.html), but note that the `DEMO_KEY` API key has harder [rate limits](https://api.data.gov/docs/rate-limits/#demo_key-rate-limits).

---

You could also download CSV dumps: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-scorecard